# How to transfer large amount of data through HTTP?

Tags: php, http, httpresponse

I'm writing a web server to be able to stream back to clients large amount data. The question is the sending data may be too large. So I cannot know the lenght of the content.

Maybe [***chunked HTTP-response***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) would help. But how can I let HTTP-client know that the data is over (end of stream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's described in [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 3.6.1:

> The chunked encoding is ended by any chunk whose size is
>      zero, followed by the trailer, which is terminated by an empty line.